# OS X Customised Quick Look plugin

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, quicklook

I need to write customised QL plugin for a file type (Let us say .xyz) that used in my application. And this .xyz contains associated video name and that video is stored in same folder.

What I need to do is:

1. Fully customised UI view which shows video and some information calculated from .xyz file.
2. Need a button "Edit" to modify file name, content and the associated video name.

Is it possible? I have gone through QL Tutorial, it seems only show the information(read-only) but cannot modify the content.

Cheers